# Are there any suggestions about how use node label in Hadoop YARN?

Tags: hadoop, scheduler, hadoop-yarn, capacity

Node label is a relatively new feature of YARN, which is available since Apache Hadoop 2.6. It can solve problems in different scenarios. However, from Hadoop JIRA and mail lists, many users encounter issues to setup and use node label.

Are there any suggestions about how use node label in Hadoop YARN?

Answer (score 0):

This is a self-answering question:

Following docs are very helpful,

- [Apache Hadoop Node Label Doc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html)
- [Tutorial of Using Node Labels](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.4/bk_yarn_resource_mgt/content/ch_node_labels.html)
- [Slides of Node Label in Hadoop Summit 15′](http://www.slideshare.net/leftnoteasy/node-labels-in-yarn)

And also you can read the blog post: [Suggestions About How To Better Use YARN Node Label](https://wangda.live/2016/04/16/suggestions-about-how-to-better-use-yarn-node-label/) which includes lots of practical suggestions as well.

Comment: Answers should be self-contained, meaning you can provide links, but please show the necessary information from them on this site

Comment: If your self-answer is three tutorials and a blog post, your question is probably too broad.

Comment: Self-answers aren't exempt from the normal requirements on answers.  Nor are questions written to be self-answered exempt from requirements on questions; if your self-answer is three tutorials and a blog post, your question is probably too broad.